# Archiving your mails with Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, archiving

I use Mozilla Thunderbird since years now. I read some articles about how to organize your mailbox most efficiently for freelancers and got an quite good-working approach for me now.

I leave everything important in my inbox (or virtual inbox for different accounts) and move all the rest to one cross-account folder structure with customer on top level and the projects on the sublevel. It works really great but at some point my folders for long-running projects get really crowded. Honestly, 99% of mails I got three years ago I don't care about.

But of course I don't want to delete all the mails because it takes time and maybe I delete the 1% important stuff.

So I'm looking for a good way to make an archive in Thunderbird, using plugins or approaches on how to archive properly?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a very bespoke archive?

Comment: I'm asking how to properly set up an archive for Thunderbird which works with a folder structure. I posted this at first at the Freelancer forum, that's why there is the organization-explanation on top :)

Comment: Ah, I understand now.

Comment: Have you looked at [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/)?

Comment: I don't want to backup everyting, I do this from time to time. I want a backup strategy which keeps my folders somehow but pushes all the old mails automatically in an local archive... Am I really the only guy in the world looking for something like this? :)